# How do I create a square grid using a ConstraintLayout with labels for the rows that are vertically centered?

Tags: android-constraintlayout, layout-gravity, constraint-layout-chains

I need to create a square grid with labels for the rows on the left side. The grid should use the entire space available on the device while keeping width=height. Because this grid has several rows and several columns automatically adjusted, I thought that using a customized `ConstraintLayout` would fit that requirement.

In the code below, which is used in a "portrait" layout, if I set the layout_width of the SCFrame view to

- `match_parent`: the size of the grid is as expected, but the `gravity` of the `textView10` and `textView11` fields is not applied
- `wrap_content`: the grid collapses to 0dpx0dp
- `0dp`: same as `wrap_content`, which in my opinion is not in line with the documentation of the `ConstraintLayout` that says "Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`"
- `xxxdp`: the SCFrame grid is square with width=xxxdp and height=xxxdp, and the `gravity` of the `textView10` and `textView11` fields is correctly applied

What should I change in the following code to get a grid that is square and uses the entire width of the screen (whatever the used device and allowing space for the labels column) and with the correct `gravity` for the labels?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scMainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_optimizationLevel="chains"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/SCFrame"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/SCFrame"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="B"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/SCFrame"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/SCFrame" />

    <be.ema.sclibrary.SCConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/SCFrame"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/A1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="this is A1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/A2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/B1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/A2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="this is A2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/A1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/B2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/B1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="this is B1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/B2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/B2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="this is B2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/B1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </be.ema.sclibrary.SCConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code for the customized ConstraintLayout:

```
class SCConstraintLayout extends android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout {
    public SCConstraintLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SCConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SCConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int chosenDimension = 0;
        int mode = 0;

        if (ScMain.isLandscapeOriented) {
            chosenDimension = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
            chosenDimension =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        }

        int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, mode);
        int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, mode);

        //        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        super.onMeasure(width, height);
    }
}
```